# Error when pasting values using macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Why can´t my code below paste values only?
The result is pastes the formula instead of the value.
Can anyone help?

Please check my code as follow :

`Sheets("Invoice Print").Activate
    Range("F21:F27").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Outgoing Goods").Select
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Range("K1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Are there any mistakes?

PS: I'm using Excel 2013.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the pasted values right in the next line with `ActiveSheet.Paste`

Also you should not use `.Select` and `Selection.`.

```
Sheets("Invoice Print").Range("F21:F27").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 1).Copy

With Sheets("Outgoing Goods")
.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Range("K1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False   

    'This line would overwrite the pasted values with not explecit values only
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Hope I could help.